# Adding a UI animated framework component with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design

I'm building a simple single-page website, and when I click a button on the page, I want to remove some content, display a loading spin bar (https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#loading-section), fetch data from an API, display the received data, and then remove the loading spinner.

However, when I try to use the material design lite spinner by adding it with jquery like so:

```
$("body").append("<div class=\"mdl-spinner mdl-js-spinner is-active\"></div>")
```

it just gives me the word Loading and no animated spinner. Is there a flaw in my understanding, or does something else need to be added for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

`Material` must be initializing some script on `load` and it will update your `spinner` `element`. But when you add later from `jquery` it will not `initialize` script. So it doesn't work.

Here is one work around for your situation. Just add spinner `div` with `display:none` like `<div id="spinner" class="mdl-spinner mdl-js-spinner is-active" style="display:none;">`. And `show/hide` div as per your requirement.

I have performed `show/hide` on button click. You can customize it based on your requirement. Check below demo.

```js
function ShowProgressBar() {
  $("#spinner").show();
  $("#show").hide();
  $("#hide").show();
}

function HideProgressBar() {
  $("#spinner").hide();
  $("#show").show();
  $("#hide").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Material Design Lite -->
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<!-- Material Design icon font -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<!-- MDL Spinner Component -->
<div id="spinner" class="mdl-spinner mdl-js-spinner is-active" style="display:none;"></div>

<div>
  <input id="show" type="button" onclick="ShowProgressBar()" value="show" />
  <input id="hide" type="button" onclick="HideProgressBar()" value="hide" style="display:none;" />
</div>
```

Comment: ah, so you mean keep it there the entire time and only display it when I want it to show up?

Comment: Yes. That's the exactly I am suggesting.